# Aplicação totalcross com imagens, quando faço o deploy para windows CE não funciona

Tags: java, totalcross

Quando faço o deploy da minha aplicação para Windows CE que contém imagens na tela ou em buttons nenhume elemento é exibido, mas no emulador funciona normalmente. Quando removo as imagens funciona normalmente.

```
public class Teste extends Container {
    private ScrollContainer sc;
    private Container contTopo,contRodape;
    private Edit edtIdentificador;
    private Button btIdentificador,btFinalizar;
    private Label lblMultiplicacao,lblMensagem;

    public void initUI() {

        setBackColor(Colors.GRAY);
        setBorderStyle(BORDER_SIMPLE);

        try {
            edtIdentificador = new Edit();
            edtIdentificador.caption = "Insira o identificador";
            edtIdentificador.setFont(Font.getFont("Lato Medium", false, edtIdentificador.getFont().size -2));
            edtIdentificador.setBackForeColors(Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK);
            edtIdentificador.requestFocus();

            btIdentificador =
                  new Button(
                      new Image("images/barra.png")
                          .hwScaledFixedAspectRatio((int) (Settings.screenDensity * 24), true));

            btIdentificador.setBorder(Button.BORDER_NONE);
            btIdentificador.setBackForeColors(Color.WHITE, Color.WHITE);

            contTopo = new Container();
            contTopo.setBackForeColors(Color.WHITE, Color.WHITE);
            add(contTopo, CENTER, TOP, PARENTSIZE, PARENTSIZE+15);
            contTopo.add(edtIdentificador, LEFT+170, TOP, PARENTSIZE+60, PARENTSIZE+80);
            contTopo.add(btIdentificador, RIGHT, TOP, PARENTSIZE+20, PARENTSIZE+100);

            lblMensagem = new Label("Adicione um indicador para listagem",CENTER);
            lblMensagem.setBackForeColors(Colors.GRAY,0x999999 );
            lblMensagem.setFont(Font.getFont("Lato Medium", false, lblMensagem.getFont().size -5));
            add(lblMensagem,CENTER,CENTER,PARENTSIZE,PARENTSIZE+10);


            contRodape = new Container();
            contRodape.setBackForeColors(Colors.GREEN, Color.WHITE);
            add(contRodape, CENTER, BOTTOM, PARENTSIZE, PARENTSIZE+10);  
            btFinalizar = new Button("Finalizar");
            btFinalizar.transparentBackground = true;
            contRodape.add(btFinalizar, RIGHT, CENTER, (int) (Settings.screenDensity * 100), PREFERRED+20);
          } catch (IOException | ImageException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu sei que você já resolveu seu problema, mas não custa nada explicar o que aconteceu para referência futura.

As imagens estavam alcançáveis no código Java. Isso significa que

1. elas estavam no *classpath* de execução do `tc.Launcher`, ou
2. elas estavam na [`CWD`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory)

porém, não necessariamente isso acontecerá no dispositivo. Quando você roda o `tc.Deploy`, não importa para onde, ele irá criar o `.tcz` referente ao seu código e aos seus *assets* para ser interpretado pela VM TotalCross no dispositivo.

Existem dois modos de se criar `.tcz`:

1. passando como argumento o caminho para o `.class` da classe principal (aquela que estende `MainWindow`)
2. passando como argumento um o caminho um `.jar`

O `.jar` pode ser usado para criar uma biblioteca de `.tcz` ou então para criar a aplicação propriamente dita. Para criar a aplicação, o nome do arquivo *precisa ser* igual ao nome da classe que estende `MainWindow` (direta ou indiretamente). Por exemplo, se eu tenho um `.jar` chamado `Marmota.jar`, e tiver alguma classe chamada `Marmota` (independente de pacote) que estenda `MainWindow`, então o `tc.Deploy` gerará um executável.

No primeira modo, o `tc.Deploy` percorrerá em profundidade, a partir da classe especificada, todas as dependências que ele precisa inserir no `.tcz`. Por dependências entenda:

1. classes cujos métodos são chamados
2. arquivos cujos nomes possam ser resolvidos em strings estaticamente povoadas *

<sup>*: não sei se procurará em todas as strings, ou apenas strings relacionadas a chamadas de métodos com nomes de arquivo</sup>

Assim, classes e *assets* que não são usados pela aplicação serão ignorados.

Quando você manda fazer o `tc.Deploy` a partir do `.jar`, não ocorrerá processamento algum de dependência e toda entrada do `.jar` será acrescida no `.tcz`.

---

No seu caso, você estava usando o TotalCross a partir do Maven. O Maven leva para o `classpath` apenas o conteúdo principal, tanto o compilado quanto os *assets*. O padrão de um projeto Maven é:

```
proj/
     |
     +- src/
     |      |
     |      +- main/
     |              |
     |              +- java/
     |              |
     |              +- resources/
     +- target/
```

O que está dentro de `src/main/java` será compilado e seu resultado posto em `target`, respeitando os pacotes. Já o conteúdo de `src/main/resources` será simplesmente copiado para `target`. No momento que você pôs a pasta `images` dentro de `resources`, ela passou a ser integrada no `target` e, portanto, passou a fazer parte do `classpath`. Enquanto ela estava na raiz do projeto, ela não fazia parte do `classpath`, porém, como no Maven o `CWD` é a raiz do projeto, ela estava acessível a nível de Java.

Uma alternativa interessante para saber se um arquivo pode ser empacotado dentro do `.tcz` é simplesmente rodar um `mvn package` na linha de comando e verificar se o arquivo está dentro do `.jar` gerado. Outra é rodar o `tc.Deploy` com a opção `/t`, em que ele testa os `.class` e lista todos os arquivos que seriam enviados para o `.tcz`.

Se quiser uma leitura mais aprofundada:

- [TotalCross Companion](https://totalcross.com/documentation/pt/api/#toc-Section-15) sobre o `tc.Deploy`
- [Artigo sobre TotalCross + GitLab CI](https://medium.com/@jeffque/trabalhando-com-totalcross-e-gitlab-ci-4e2f7e376c18), derivado de experiências minhas no trabalho

Comment: Excelente resposta! ficou muito detalhado algumas coisas que não entendi. Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

As imagens estavam em uma pasta images, após colocar a pasta images dentro da source foolder "src/main/resources" as imagens apareceram  na aplicação

Answer (score 1):

Eu vi o teu código alí e fui testar no meu pc e funcionou, eu vou o meu código aqui para tu ver como ficou e verificar com o teu código para ver se tem algo diferente.

public class Teste extends Container{
     private ScrollContainer sc;
       private Container contTopo,contRodape;
       private Edit edtIdentificador;
       private Button btIdentificador,btFinalizar;
       private Label lblMultiplicacao,lblMensagem;

```
   public void initUI() {

       setBackColor(0xDDDDDD);
       setBorderStyle(BORDER_SIMPLE);

       try {
           edtIdentificador = new Edit();
           edtIdentificador.caption = "Insira o identificador";
           edtIdentificador.setFont(Font.getFont("Lato Medium", false, edtIdentificador.getFont().size -2));
           edtIdentificador.setBackForeColors(Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK);
           edtIdentificador.requestFocus();

           btIdentificador =
                 new Button(
                     new Image("images/barra.png")
                         .hwScaledFixedAspectRatio((int) (Settings.screenDensity * 24), true));

           btIdentificador.setBorder(Button.BORDER_NONE);
           btIdentificador.setBackForeColors(Color.WHITE, Color.WHITE);

           contTopo = new Container();
           contTopo.setBackForeColors(Color.WHITE, Color.WHITE);
           add(contTopo, CENTER, TOP, PARENTSIZE, PARENTSIZE+15);
           contTopo.add(edtIdentificador, LEFT+170, TOP, PARENTSIZE+60, PARENTSIZE+80);
           contTopo.add(btIdentificador, RIGHT, TOP, PARENTSIZE+20, PARENTSIZE+100);

           lblMensagem = new Label("Adicione um indicador para listagem",CENTER);
           lblMensagem.setBackForeColors(0xDDDDDD,0x999999 );
           lblMensagem.setFont(Font.getFont("Lato Medium", false, lblMensagem.getFont().size -5));
           add(lblMensagem,CENTER,CENTER,PARENTSIZE,PARENTSIZE+10);


           contRodape = new Container();
           contRodape.setBackForeColors(Color.GREEN, Color.WHITE);
           add(contRodape, CENTER, BOTTOM, PARENTSIZE, PARENTSIZE+10);
           btFinalizar = new Button("Finalizar");
           btFinalizar.transparentBackground = true;
           contRodape.add(btFinalizar, RIGHT, CENTER, (int) (Settings.screenDensity * 100), PREFERRED+20);
         } catch (Exception e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
        }
   }
```

}

não entendi o porque do slack só ter colocado organizado a partir do initUI, mas ta ai o código que gerou o apk foi esse ai, se ainda continuar dando erro da uma olhada na pom.xml talvez tenha algo errado lá. Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: O problema era minha estrutura de pastas, estava assim:

proj/
     |
     +- src/
     |      |
     |      +- main/
     |              |
     |              +- java/
     |              |
     |              +- images/
     +- target/


Enquanto o correto era assim(Explicado por Jefferson Quesado):

proj/
     |
     +- src/
     |      |
     |      +- main/
     |              |
     |              +- java/
     |              |
     |              +- resources/
     |                          |
     |                          +- images/
     +- target/